# Firefox addon sdk close multiple tabs for same domain

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there any way to close multiple tabs under same domain ?

I know that add-on sdk have it but only for **activeTab**.
I want to use it when Firefox update my add-on.

Thank you!

Comment: This is a good Q. To be E10s friendly, for non sdk, we would have to load a framescript to each tab, and tell it to tell us what is the site loaded. Only the current tab url can be access without needing a framscript. So for sdk, Im not sure but they probably have some nice tab iterator thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [sdk tabs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs) module; iterate the tabs and match the `url` with the domain in subject.

For the matching part, you can also use the [match-pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/util_match-pattern) module.

Something like:

```
const tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
const { MatchPattern } = require("sdk/util/match-pattern");

const mozillaDomain = new MatchPattern("*.mozilla.org");

for (let tab of tabs) {
  if (mozillaDomain.test(tab.url))
    tab.close();
}
```